# Not Found: /hello/

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hellow, World !")
```

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlspattern=[
    path("",views.index,name="index")
]

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include,path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("hello/", include("hello.urls"))
]


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'hello',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Error I am gettting is

Using the URLconf defined in helloproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, hello/, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo error on urlpattern

```
urlspattern=[
    path("",views.index,name="index")
]
```

you have to change that to

```
urlpatterns=[
    path("",views.index,name="index")
]
```

Comment: so , we must have same name for that variable. can u explain me why?

Comment: `urlpatterns` is like a keyword for Django. You can not have any other name for it otherwise Django won't be able to find your URL patterns

Comment: Whenever you put any file name in include() or in root_url so django tries to find the list name urlpatterns on that file for url routing that is the reason you cant change that

Answer (score 0):

In this line change `urlpattern` to `urlpatterns`

```
urlpatterns=[
    path("",views.index,name="index")
]
```